# How to extract column names which have a specific value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of column names  which contains column names , I am iterating a row and checking if it contains 1 then appending that column name  to a list.Can It be better using zip or something.

```
private def getNames(row: Row): List[String] = {
 val listofColumnNames = row.schema.fields.map(_.name).toList
    val listOfColumnWhichContainOne =  ArrayBuffer[String]()
    listofColumnNames.indices.foreach(index => {
      if(row.getInt(index).equals(1)) {
        listOfColumnWhichContainOne.append(listofColumnNames(index))
      }
    })
    listofColumnNames.toList
}
```

Can It be simplified ?

Comment: can you post your actual schema & expected schema ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column to an existing dataframe that contains a list of all columns in which for that particular row the field has the value `1`.

Within the column paramater of [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) you can iterate over all other columns and check for the wanted value:

```scala
val df = Seq((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (3, 2, 1)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
df.show()

val cols = df.schema.fieldNames //change this array according to your needs
                                //if you want to exclude columns from the check

df.withColumn("result", array(
   cols.map {
       c: String => when(col(c).equalTo(1), c)
       }: _*
)).show()
```

prints:

```
//input data
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   4|   5|   6|
|   3|   1|   1|
+----+----+----+

//result
+----+----+----+--------------+
|col1|col2|col3|        result|
+----+----+----+--------------+
|   1|   2|   3|      [col1,,]|
|   4|   5|   6|          [,,]|
|   3|   1|   1|[, col2, col3]|
+----+----+----+--------------+
```